# Is "to which X" an alternate to "where X to"?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering if these two are equivalent.

Example:

> It's a place to which our souls ascend.
>
> It's a place where our souls ascend to.

Are these two the same in meaning broadly speaking?

Comment: The placement of the preposition ("to") doesn't matter.  So you're really asking if *the place which our souls ascend to* and *the place where our souls ascend to* have the same meaning.

Comment: Don't use "where" with the second one: "the place our souls ascend to".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those two sentences have exactly the same meaning.

It could also be phrased:

> It's a place to where our souls ascend.
>
> It's a place which our souls ascend to.
>
> It's a place our souls ascend to.
>
> It's where our souls ascend to.

And there are many more options as well.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, yes, those sentences mean the same thing.

In the little details they are slightly different:

- "The place to which" always indicates movement/direction.
- "The place where" is broader and can indicate location/origin (i.e.,
  the place where I live, eat, work, etc.)

Though I understand the second sentence, it sounds a little strange to my ear-- that final "to" makes me expect an object or an infinitive. 
Example:

- It's the place where our souls ascend to [the afterlife].
- It's the place where students go to [play soccer].